# Synchronization between two databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, client

I am trying to achieve sync between client database (mdf file) and SQL Server database. The sync has to be done for only some tables and not all. Also in one of the table, it just need to sync only some data based on a criteria (like say sync between client and server only if the UserName is 'xxxxx'. Can anyone please help me? It will be good if a sample can be provided.

Comment: have you found any solution, suggestion or anything in this regard?

Comment: @AzazulHaq - I did not get a solution for this. However i tried the sync framework (with sdf client and SQL Server). I was able to perform the synchronization for the tables which i needed and also based on some filters as well. Also between two sql servers I am using a replication technique to achieve the synchronization. However i tried for syncing all the tables and data here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the SQLCE 3.5 sync with SQL Server database using Microsoft Sync Framework. Using the tombstone tables and tracking columns, the db is synched. Can help if anyone request in this post as it is a big code. I will try to share it in document